# Getting first and last element of list<string> giving me ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION error

Tags: c++, list, stl

```
list<string> logs;
GetLogs(logs);
string first=logs.front();
**string last=logs.back();**
```

At this point I'm getting progeam got SIGILL in GDB

My GetLogs() function definition is:

```
int GetLogs(list<string>& logs){
logs.push_back("Log.001");
logs.push_back("Log.002");
logs.push_back("Log.003");
return 0;
}
```

When Program got this error I can see the values 
p first
Log.001
p last
Log.003

What's wrong with my code??

Comment: Does it do this when the code you've shown is the only thing (besides includes etc) in a program?

Comment: Could you come up with a minimal but complete example that exhibits the problem, and post that?

Comment: Its a fragment making the problem..Its a very big code. Are the includes and all needed?? stdlib and stdio are there.

Comment: @ NPE please give me a moment. I'm on it

Comment: what happens when you do `string last = logs.back()` within `GetLogs` as the last statement?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Sorry guys but GDB was showing the SIGILL error on the wrong line.
I was getting the error because we have a logging mechanism which uses formatted input like `fprintf`. But I gave `%s` with `string` that is making this problem. Thanks you so much for your patience

`first.c_str()` and `last.c_str()` solved it.